# Format Array date and time on Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

I'm would like to use Array Formula to use the data from another sheet and obtain only the Date from the Date and Time Data.

Example, In Sheet 1, there will be a list of date and time date.

- Nov 15, 2022, 2:34 PM

In Sheet 2, I would like to use a formula to return the date without the time:

- 15 Nov 2022

Comment: What about `=DATEVALUE(Sheet1!A1)`?

Comment: For dynamic spill array. `=INDEX(DATEVALUE(Sheet1!A1:INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A,COUNTA(Sheet1!A1:A))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula-

```
=INDEX(DATEVALUE(Sheet1!A1:INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A,COUNTA(Sheet1!A1:A))))
```

Or `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:A,"select A where A is not null format A 'dd-mmm-yyyy'")
```

> Edit: Use below formulas-

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>""),",","",1),","),,1)
```

Then use cell format as desired date formats. Or below `QUERY()` function to format it.

```
=QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>""),",","",1),","),,1),"format Col1 'dd mmm yyyy'")
```

[image]

Comment: Encountered Error for Index() formula "DATEVALUE parameter 'Nov 15, 2022, 1:18 PM' cannot be parsed to date/time". For Query(), it return the date and time.

Comment: Then they are not true dates. They are strings. If so, then you have to use few string manipulation formula to convert them to dates.

Comment: Can you share sample google-sheet so that we can check.

Comment: Here is the link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wOhGHdRglCsk8D8uebjkGPOkirhSWSzM2cpyFPNaj3s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user20595599 Check my edited answer. [Check this sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tvVFFmdm140D9VcWf-zp7q2mx-r_mBAkshd365fdiDI/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I managed to extract the date.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Convert into `string` (without the need to specify the format)

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXT('Sheet 1'!A2:A,"dd MMM yyyy"))
```

---

**Method 2:**

Extact the `date` value and set the format

```
=ArrayFormula(DATEVALUE('Sheet 1'!A2:A))
```

Format: `dd MMM yyyy`

---

Reference:

- [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)
- [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039)

Comment: To ignore blanks `=ArrayFormula(IF(Sheet1!A2:A="",,DATEVALUE(Sheet1!A2:A)))`.

Comment: Method 1 return both the date and time. Encountered error for method 2 "DATEVALUE parameter 'Nov 15, 2022, 1:18 PM' cannot be parsed to date/time".